# Animate/Customise user's current location on Google maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I have implemented the Google maps SDK in my project. And I want the map to show user's location. Now the thing is, It does show user's location with compass and all, but I want to put a custom image or a pulsating image like default IOS maps.
Please help , because I tried searching hard, but did not get any results.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/marker

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/

Comment: Yes. Read this. But that is for a GMSMarker. Not user's Current location.